# the hover dropdown menu is not working well

Tags: html, css

I work on a new website, and now I am styling the navbar

I have created a dropdown menu with hover but the menu does not take the list's height as I think so when I hover to the next list in the dropdown menu, the menu disappears.

[image]

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5rem 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li {
  color: #d3d3d3;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  background: #00f;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 150%;
}

.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  height: 150%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <h1>Hexa</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <!-- Nav Menu -->
    <li class="active">Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried to change the parent list height and the menu inside it but still now working, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue, can you edit as runnable [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or codepen?

Comment: Done, but - I don't know why - it works well here, and still doesn't work well on chrome as index.html file

Comment: If it works here, but not on your actual website, perhaps it doesn't have to do with the component itself, but a CSS property from another part of your website. Have you tried a page with nothing other than your navigation bar? Perhaps you have a base CSS file which is interfering?

Comment: @MadCreativity yes, the header under the navbar is using slick slider. 

it works well [here](https://codepen.io/timbeckett/pen/PoqbpXL) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help :D

I just added the `z-index` property to the menu and it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

I work on a new website, and now I am styling the navbar

I have created a dropdown menu with hover but the menu does not take the list's height as I think so when I hover to the next list in the dropdown menu, the menu disappears.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5rem 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li {
  color: #d3d3d3;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  background: #00f;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.menu li:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 150%;
}

.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
}

.menu li:nth-child(4):hover ul{
  height: 150%;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  opacity: 1;

  overflow: hidden;
}


.menu li:nth-child(4) ul{
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(250px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li:nth-child(4) ul li{
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
}

.menu li:nth-child(4) ul li a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <h1>Hexa</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <!-- Nav Menu -->
    <li class="active">Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent Link</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```